# How do i acess a variable outside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to access  const newdata outside a function

```
    function updateFields(response) {
        $("#FIELDSET").removeProp('disabled');

        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
        const data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("responses")[0].innerHTML;
        const rdata = data.split('//')[0]
        const payload = data.split(':1:1,')
            .map(x => x.split('='))
            .reduce((obj, x) => {
                obj[x[0].replace(/\./g, '_')] = x[1];
                return obj;
            }, {})

        const newdat="string";


        CO_CODE=payload.CO_CODE.split(':1:1')[0]
        const {AMOUNT, INT_RATE, TERM, FREQUENCY, REP_START_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID, INSTALMENT} = payload;

    }
```

Comment: `const` are block scoped.  You cannot access it outside the function.  Either raise the scope of the variable to a higher scope, or `return newdat` at the end of the function

Comment: You can declare `newdat` as `let` outside your function scope, then set value inside function

Comment: And you should not. Your code is mixing all kinds of responsibilities together.
Create a data structure and have a logic function to do the work and expose that

Comment: lets say i add a variable like var dom="123456"; how do i access it outside the function. thanks

Comment: `var` are function scoped.  You also cannot access those outside the function.  Same solution applies

Comment: I feel like this an event handler/callback so he cannot return a value out of it nor hoist it out as the callback runs asynchronous to his other code.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You could assign the value to a variable declared outside of your function, but since your `const newdat` is scoped within the function, you won't be able to access it outside of it.

Something like this:

```
let newdat;
function updateFields(response) {
    $("#FIELDSET").removeProp('disabled');

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
    const data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("responses")[0].innerHTML;
    const rdata = data.split('//')[0]
    const payload = data.split(':1:1,')
        .map(x => x.split('='))
        .reduce((obj, x) => {
            obj[x[0].replace(/\./g, '_')] = x[1];
            return obj;
        }, {})

    newdat="string";


    CO_CODE=payload.CO_CODE.split(':1:1')[0]
    const {AMOUNT, INT_RATE, TERM, FREQUENCY, REP_START_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID, INSTALMENT} = payload;

}
```

Though be mindful that in this case, since the variable declaration is left undefined, you might want to test it before using it OR define it to a default value, like an empty string, when declaring it.

Comment: Your answer does not contain a suggested solution, so it is not necessary. Use comments instead... //edit: NOW it contains :)

Comment: @Toxi This is pretty much a solution, it suggests what to do in the first part.

Comment: I'm wondering why, given how it doesn't change, that it can't be `const newdat = "string"` outside.

Comment: I added the code to represent what I meant by that. Is this better? Otherwise, I'll simply delete the answer.

Comment: If you declare it outside with const, you won't know what you'll want to assign to it within the function. When the function tries to assign something to it, it won't let you. You can declare object structures with const and modify the value of their properties, but declaring a string with const prevents the variable binding from referencing a different value.

Answer (score 2):

```
let newdat;
function updateFields(response) {
  $("#FIELDSET").removeProp('disabled');

  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
  const data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("responses")[0].innerHTML;
  const rdata = data.split('//')[0]
  const payload = data.split(':1:1,')
      .map(x => x.split('='))
      .reduce((obj, x) => {
          obj[x[0].replace(/\./g, '_')] = x[1];
          return obj;
      }, {})

  newdat="string";


  CO_CODE=payload.CO_CODE.split(':1:1')[0]
  const {AMOUNT, INT_RATE, TERM, FREQUENCY, REP_START_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID, INSTALMENT} = payload;

}
/* run the function */
console.log(newdat); // string
```

Answer (score 0):

If `newdat` is not specific to — or specifically dependent upon — your `updateFields` method, you could maintain it outside of `updateFields` scope; updating it whenever `updateFields` is called.

```
let newdat = '';
function updateFields() {
    // ...
    newdat = "string";
    // ...
}

function someOtherFunction() {
    console.log( 'newdat =' + newdat ); // would log the current value of `newdat` when called
}
```

```js
let newdat = '';

function updateFields() {
  newdat = "string";
}

function someOtherFunction() {
  console.log('newdat = ' + newdat); // would log the current value of `newdat` when called
}

updateFields();
someOtherFunction();
```

Comment: its saying undefined when i do a console.log

Comment: In my example, you would have to call both, starting with `updateFields()`, in order to see `newdat` come back as `"string"`; otherwise, it should be an empty string — but not strictly `undefined`.